# XP & CR for Monsters with magic equipment?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, cr-calculation

Suppose I have a monster. OK he's not really a monster, he's just Knight like the one on page 347 of the monster manual. Only this particular Knight has a Spellguard Shield as described on page 201 of the Dungeon Master's Guide. Obviously he's going to be more hearty an adversary, but how do I calculate the appropriate Challenge Rating and Experience Points for this Knight? And more generally, how does one calculate the CR & XP of NPCs with magic gear?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Have you been through the relevant steps in the DMG for calculating a monster's CR? If so then can you provide more details on how that doesn't answer the question and what specifically you find confusing?

Comment: Hi Da Coyote, it looks like you've created two accounts by accident; you can [follow these instructions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge them. Once you do you'll be able to vote for the answers here, leave comments, and mark one as accepted if one of them solved your problem.

Answer (score 7):

The section "Creating a Monster" in chapter 9 of the DMG has guidelines for calculating monster CR. But they are just that: guidelines, rather than rules.

CR can be a pretty vague concept to pin down and even the official monsters can be easier or harder than their CR would indicate, depending on the capabilities of the party. For example, a monster with resistance or immunity to a damage type can be an easy encounter or a hard encounter depending on whether the party has weapons or spells that can get past that resistance!

In your case, the Knight is a relatively low-level "monster" but the Spellguard Shield is a rare and relatively powerful defensive item. If your party is mainly composed of melee combatants then this will likely make no difference. If your party is composed entirely of spellcasters then this item could make the encounter harder.

Nevertheless, looking at the table and the guidelines, adding this item is probably equivalent to raising the Knight's AC/saves by 2-4 (see Step 15: Saving Throw Bonuses). So this would likely raise the CR by 1 or 2.

Answer (score 3):

## CR increases by 1

The AC of the Knight changes from 18 to 20, because of the shield. At the same time, the damage is reduced from 20 (2 x 2d6+3) to 15 (2 x 1d8+3).

According to the DMG, Creating a Monster section, the Magic Resistance is calculated as +2 AC, and I would add 1 more for the disadvantage on spell attacks.
So the effective AC is 23, bringing the defensive CR to a weak 5.
At the same time, the offensive CR does not change, 15 and 20 being the lower and upper bounds of the same CR respectively. It remains 4, but just barely.

In the end, I would calculate with CR 4, as both defensive and offensive CRs were very close to being one lower.

## I would not change the XP value

Unless they have to deliver the shield for someone, the reward beyond the XP value and standard treasure of a CR 3 monster is exactly worth a Spellguard Shield.